# What do we mean by $CP^2$ with reverse orientation?

Tags: differential-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

$CP^2$ and $\bar{CP^2}$ are not diffeomorphic since they have non-isomorphic intersection forms. so why do we call the latter $CP^2$ with reverse orientation? it seems like we are not just reversing a given orentation on $CP^2$ to get $\bar {CP^2}$.

Comment: Maybe im misunderstanding your question but the two spaces are certainly diffeomorphic (its the same manifold!).  The point is that there is no *orientation preserving* diffeomorphism from $CP^2$ to $\bar{CP}^2$.  In other words there is no *orientation reversing* automorphism of $CP^2$.